# FindCycle Evaluation Time Diverges

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have a data set of 257,182 edges between 32,849 vertices forming a directed graph. I would like to use `FindCycle` to analyse its cycle structure. Unsurprisingly, this graph appears to be too large and `FindCycle` chokes. I tried a more modest target with the command

```
FindCycle[g, {3}, All];
```

where g is the graph. I am not providing the graph data for obvious reasons and also because it is confidential. Hopefully it's still OK for me to ask this question without a **mcve** or **mwe**. In any case, the above command does not complete even if I use only the first 100,000 edges (I killed it after 14 hrs: I have a MacBook Pro with a 2.6 GHz i7 processor and 32GB of RAM, running MMA 12 on Mojave). So I lowered the target again by starting with a graph corresponding to the first 10,000 edges and gradually increasing the size until I got to about 90,000 edges, at which point I saw the CPU time diverge.

My question is: is there some parameter like allocated RAM that could be increased to push the point of divergence farther out?

I tried this:

```
<< JLink`;
InstallJava[];
(* Allocate 8GB of RAM *)
ReinstallJava[JVMArguments -> "-Xmx8g"];
```

But I actually do not know whether Java is even relevant. I looked for memory management posts but could not find anything I could use. I tried looking up CUDALink but GPU programming is more advanced than what I can handle without dedicating weeks of study, which I would rather avoid if possible.

To give more context, I attach 3 figures that summarise my experiments. To estimate the memory usage (in MB) I used:

```
MaxMemoryUsed[]/1048576 // N
```

after each step of the analysis, where each new step consisted in adding 10,000 new edges to the graph. For the sake of completeness, I used this code to generate the graph:

```
Clear[g];
iStart = 0;
g = Graph[
  Flatten[
   Table[
    {dataIn[[i, 2]] -> dataIn[[i, 1]]}, {i, iStart + 1, iStart + 20000}
    ]
   ]
  ]
```

shown here for the second step. As the figures below show, I tried starting the graph from the 100,001st edge and performing the same analysis increasing the number of edges up to divergence. Figures 1 and 2 show that there isn't a divergence in the number of cycles or in the RAM used.

[image: Figure 1]

[image: Figure 2]

[image: Figure 3]

The divergence point for the red data corresponds to a graph of 21861 vertices and 86000 edges. The blue data diverges around the point corresponding to a graph of 23453 vertices and 97000 edges.

I realise that these are large numbers but am just wondering if anyone who is more familiar with `FindCycle` and/or with graph theory can tell me if I have simply found the limit for what this function can do due to combinatorial explosion or if there is anything that could be tweaked to enable MMA to analyse a bigger graph in useful time.

Of course I can also pick up Godsyl and Royle's graph theory book, which I might well do, but I remain curious about whether there might be any limits in the `FindCycle` algorithm itself.

Comment: Do you need _all cycles of all sizes_, or do you need only small ones, such as 3-cycles or 4-cycles?

Comment: I need all cycles of all sizes, but I don't mind breaking that down into n separate commands to find cycles from 2 to n hops separately, where n could be up to maybe 50.

Comment: There are exponentially many cycles in general, so hitting a wall with the graph size is quite expected. In almost all cases, listing all cycles is simply not feasible in large networks. I would suggest looking for an analysis technique that does not depend on having _all_ cycles. There are several possibilities, but it is hard to suggest anything without knowing your application.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the pointers. I think it's time to study some algebra! The application is obligation-clearing in the trade credit market, see this recent paper: https://www.mdpi.com/1911-8074/13/12/295